# Alert box in Waitr Webdriver

Tags: macos, firefox, watir, webdriver

I had a look here: http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/JavaScript+Pop+Ups

Every solution is for IE on Windows. I am using Firefox on Mac. Is there a way to click on OK of a JavaScript alert box?

Answer (score 4):

Proper handling of alerts and prompts is still [being worked on](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=27) in WebDriver, but a common workaround is to overwrite the window functions using execute_script(), i.e.

```
browser.execute_script("window.alert = function(msg) { window.lastAlert = msg; }")
browser.button(:id => "trigger-alert").click
browser.execute_script("return window.lastAlert") #=> "the message"
```

Since I'd like to avoid a bunch of monkey patches floating around (a common problem in the Watir community), I've added some [helper methods](http://github.com/jarib/watir-webdriver/commit/8fd5fd2a35c252fe4b72d401a655b01abb16b916) as an optional require - after the next release you should be able to do:

```
require "watir-webdriver/extensions/alerts"

browser.alert do
  browser.button(:id => "alert").click 
end #=> "the alert message"

browser.confirm(true) do
  browser.button(:id => "confirm").click
end #=> "the confirm message"  

browser.prompt("returned value") do
  browser.button(:id => "prompt").click 
end #=> { :message => "foo", :default => "bar" }
```

Note that this is temporary and the API may be removed in the future when the issue is resolved in WebDriver.

UPDATE:

Proper alert handling is now implemented. The above example would now be done like this:

```
browser.button(:id => "alert").click
browser.alert.ok

browser.button(:id => "confirm").click
browser.alert.ok # or browser.alert.close

browser.button(:id => "prompt").click
alert = browser.alert
alert.text #=> "foo"
alert.ok
```

Comment: I had an error using browser.alert and I fixed it with a hack, but you might want to had a look: http://gist.github.com/569969

Comment: The current behaviour is correct - if the button doesn't exist, it should raise an error. The idea is that you will write your own code in the block that will trigger the alert.

Comment: Sorry, I was calling it in the wrong place. However I tried your code but does not click any alert: assert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:value=>"OK", :tag_name=>"button"}

Comment: The code in the block should contain the action needed to *trigger* the alert. Check out the tests here http://github.com/jarib/watir-webdriver/blob/master/spec/alert_spec.rb and the corresponding HTML here http://github.com/jarib/watir-webdriver/blob/master/spec/html/alerts.html for an example of how it works.

Comment: The links in Jarib's comment are broken since watir is now it's own thing.   https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/master/spec/html/alerts.html  https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/master/spec/html/alerts.html